# How can I extract a string prefix that comes before a given character?

Tags: rust

Is there a way of extracting a prefix defined by a character without using `split`? For instance, given "some-text|more-text" how can I extract "some-text" which is the string that comes before "|"?

Comment: Why no `split`? `.split('|').next()` is probably the most direct way to get `"some-text"` from your input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split may be the best way. But, if for whatever reason you want to do it without `.split()`, here's a couple alternatives.

You can use the `.chars()` iterator, chained with `.take_while()`, then produce a String with `.collect()`.

```rust
// pfx will be "foo".
let pfx = "foo|bar".chars()
                   .take_while(|&ch| ch != '|')
                   .collect::<String>();
```

Another way, which is pretty efficient, but fallable, is to create a slice of the original `str`:

```rust
let s   = "foo|bar";
let pfx = &s[..s.find('|').unwrap()];

// or - if used in a function/closure that returns an `Option`.
let pfx = &s[..s.find('|')?];
```

Answer (score 6):

If your issue with `split` is that it may also split rest of the string, then consider `str.splitn(2, '|')` which splits into maximum two parts, so you get the string up to the first `|` and then the rest of the string even if it contains other `|` characters.

Answer (score 1):

as @Kornel point out, you can use the `Split` function:

```rust
let raw_text = "some-text|more-text";
let extracted_text = raw_text.split("|").next().unwrap();
```

```html
 
<iframe src="https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&code=fn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20raw_text%20%3D%20%22some-text%7Cmore-text%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20extracted_text%20%3D%20raw_text.split(%22%7C%22).next().unwrap()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%7D%22%2Cextracted_text)%3B%0A%7D" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></iframe>
```